# Merge hour_index dataframe with day_index dataframe and fill all rows with same value from day_index dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge

I currently have two dataframes, one indexed on `hour`, other indexed on 
`day`.

```
df1
                      col1    col2   col3
datetime
2018-03-01 10:00       1        2      3
2018-03-01 11:00       1        2      3 
2018-03-01 12:00       1        2      3


df2
                col4      col5
datetime
2018-03-01       10        20 
2018-03-02       10        20 
2018-03-03       10        20
```

I want to merge the two dataframes so that I can add values from `col4` and `col5` onto the df1 but in a way that all rows on df1 are filled with corresponding value from df2, not just a single row for each day.

If I do below:

```
df_merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I get:

```
    df1
                      col1    col2   col3   col4   col5
datetime
2018-03-01 10:00       1        2      3     10      20
2018-03-01 11:00       1        2      3     NaN     NaN
2018-03-01 12:00       1        2      3     NaN     NaN...
```

Is there a way so that I fill the `NaN` with `10` and `20` as well? So all the hours on `2018-03-01` should be filled with same values for `col4` and `col5`...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and merge by it with `left_on`:

```
a = df1.index.floor('d')
df_merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', left_on=a, right_index=True)
print (df_merge)
                         key_0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
datetime                                                    
2018-03-01 10:00:00 2018-03-01   1.0   2.0   3.0    10    20
2018-03-01 11:00:00 2018-03-01   1.0   2.0   3.0    10    20
2018-03-01 12:00:00 2018-03-01   1.0   2.0   3.0    10    20
2018-03-01 12:00:00 2018-03-02   NaN   NaN   NaN    10    20
2018-03-01 12:00:00 2018-03-03   NaN   NaN   NaN    10    20
```

If necessary remove column filled by datetimes:

```
a = df1.index.floor('d')
df_merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='outer', left_on=a, right_index=True).drop('key_0', 1)
print (df_merge)
                     col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
datetime                                         
2018-03-01 10:00:00   1.0   2.0   3.0    10    20
2018-03-01 11:00:00   1.0   2.0   3.0    10    20
2018-03-01 12:00:00   1.0   2.0   3.0    10    20
2018-03-01 12:00:00   NaN   NaN   NaN    10    20
2018-03-01 12:00:00   NaN   NaN   NaN    10    20
```

Also it seems left join is necessary here:

```
a = df1.index.floor('d')
df_merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', left_on=a, right_index=True)
print (df_merge)

                     col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
datetime                                         
2018-03-01 10:00:00     1     2     3    10    20
2018-03-01 11:00:00     1     2     3    10    20
2018-03-01 12:00:00     1     2     3    10    20
```